# crontab path difficulties

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run a scheduled task on my remote server from within Parallels Plesk Panel 9.2.2 and I am trouble trying to figure out what the correct path I should be using is. I tried the URL of the file  (what you would type into the browser to find it) but that doesn't work.

Can someone please give me the format I should be using, eg username/root_directory/filename.php? Or any suggestions that I could use to investigate this issue further?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Cron runs programs, not web sites, so you must provide the path on disk to a command line program or script. You appear to have a PHP script so you have a number of alternatives:

## 1

Provide the path to the PHP CLI interpreter and pass your script as argument:

```
php /home/username/root_directory/filename.php
```

... or:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/username/root_directory/filename.php
```

## 2

Create a [PHP shell script](http://www.myokyawhtun.com/tips-tricks/how-to-run-php-script-in-shell.html):

```
/home/username/filename.sh
```

... where filename.sh has "x" permission and looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo “Hello World!”;
?>
```

## 3

Create a bash shell script:

```
/home/username/filename.sh
```

... where filename.sh has "x" permission and looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/username/root_directory/filename.php
```

... or:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /home/username/root_directory/filename.php
```

## 4

Run an app that can talk HTTP:

```
wget http://example.com/filename.php
```